# Write a function that used cloned inputs

Tags: jquery, function, dynamic

I am having a little problem here.

I have a form where I would like the user to be able to add rows to the form by clicking a button.

I am able to clone the row and change the id for each of them but now I want to be able to use those new inputs in a function, but I don't know how. 
Here is what I have.

I want the user to enter values for each of the fields then upon entering all the numbers for each row a number I want the total box in each row to display (acwatts*hours)*quantity.

How can I write a function that will use the new fields even if they haven't been created yet?

Here is the jquery for my clone function.

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {

     var clone = $('#applianceTable tbody>tr:nth-child(2)').clone(true);
         clone.find(":input").val("");  
         clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
         return val + count;
    });

        clone.insertBefore('#addCalc');
        count++;

    });
});
```

Here is the javascript for the function I attempted to write but I'd gladly change it to jquery

```
function Calc()
{
//lets get the entered numbers
var acwatts_holder=parseInt(document.getElementById('acwatts').value);
var quantity_holder=parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
var hours_holder=parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value);
//ok lets do our calculations
var total=(acwatts_holder*hours_holder)*quantity_holder;
//now printing the result back on forms
document.load_calc.total1.value=total;
}
```

here is the HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8" bgcolor="#083972"    id="applianceTable">
<thead bgcolor="#083972">
<td colspan="6" bgcolor="#083972" align="center"><span class="title3">Load Evaluation Calculator</span></td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#e4e4e4" align="center">
<th width="30%">Appliance</th>
<th width="10%">Quantity</th>
<th width="15%">AC Watts</th>
<th width="15%">DC Watts</th>
<th width="15%">Hours per Day</th>
<th width="15%">Total Watt hours per Day</th>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#e4e4e4" align="center" class="row_to_clone"> 
<form name="load_calc" >
<td width="30%"><input type "number" name="appliance" id="appliance" size="50"  /></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="5" value="" />     </td>
<td width="15%"><input type="number" name="acwatts" id="acwatts" value=""size="15" /></td>
<td width="15%"><input type="number" name="dcwatts" id="dcwatts" value="" size="15" /> </td>
<td width="15%"><input type="number" name="hours" id="hours" value="" size="5" onkeyup="Calc();" /></td>
<td width="15%"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" disabled="disabled"></td>
</form>
</tr>
<tr id="addCalc">
<td width="10%" ><input type="button" id="add" value="Add Another Appliance"></td> 
<td colspan="6" align="right"> <input type="button" name="calculating" value="CALCULATE" onclick="CalcTotal();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="right" bgcolor="#083972"><p style="color:#ffffff;">Your System Should be at least<input type="text" name="totalSystem" readonly="readonly">kWh</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems

1. Id of an element must be unique... in your case all the cloned elements have the input fields with the same id. So in this case the input fields need not have the ID attribute
2. Your html is invalid, `tr` cannot have `form` as the child

Try

```
<input type="number" name="hours" id="hours" value="" size="5" onkeyup="Calc(this);" />
```

and

```
function Calc(el) {
    var $tr = $(el).closest('tr');
    var acwatts_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="acwatts"]').val()) || 0;
    var quantity_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="quantity"]').val()) || 0;
    var hours_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="hours"]').val()) || 0;
    //ok lets do our calculations
    var total = (acwatts_holder * hours_holder) * quantity_holder;
    //now printing the result back on forms
    $tr.find('input[name="total"]').val(total)
console.log($tr, $tr.find('input[name="total"]'))
    //lets get the entered numbers
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9bsey/)

But i think it will be better to use event delegation to solve this issue like

```
$('#applianceTable').on('keyup change', 'input[name="acwatts"], input[name="quantity"], input[name="hours"]', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var acwatts_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="acwatts"]').val()) || 0;
    var quantity_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="quantity"]').val()) || 0;
    var hours_holder = parseInt($tr.find('input[name="hours"]').val()) || 0;
    //ok lets do our calculations
    var total = (acwatts_holder * hours_holder) * quantity_holder;
    //now printing the result back on forms
    $tr.find('input[name="total"]').val(total)
    //lets get the entered numbers

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HZEL2/)